# Hadoop secondary sort for values. Sorting, gorping loose values

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, partitioning

It's rather common problem, I don't understand what to pick.

I have fields: **id, creationDate, state, dateDiff**

**id** is a **natural key**.

I need to get in my reducer:

**KEY(id), VALUE(creationDate, state, dateDiff)**

**VALUE(creationDate, state, dateDiff) should be sorted by: creationDate, state**

What key should I have to pick?
I did create **composite key (id, creationDate, state)**

I did **implement** 
partitioner by **id**

grouper by **id**

**sorter** by **id, creationDate,state**

My reducer gets only unique id...
For example:

```
1 123 true  6
1 456 false 6
1 789 true  7
```

I get only

```
1 123 true  6
```

In my reducer. Seems like I don't get sorter, partitioner, grouper :( There is a luxk of understanding.

Here is my code:

```
public class POIMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, XVLRKey, XVLRValue>{

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(POIMapper.class);

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text csvLine, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Pair<XVLRKey, XVLRValue> xvlrPair = POIUtil.parseKeyAndValue(csvLine.toString(), POIUtil.CSV_DELIMITER);
        context.write(xvlrPair.getValue0(), xvlrPair.getValue1());
    }

}

public class POIReducer extends Reducer<XVLRKey, XVLRValue, LongWritable, Text>{

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(POIReducer.class);

    private final Text textForOutput = new Text();

    @Override()
    public void reduce(XVLRKey key, Iterable<XVLRValue> values, Context context)
                                                                            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        XVLROutput out = null;
//Just check that values are correctly attached to keys. No logic here...
        LOG.info("\nPOIReducer: key:"+key);
        for(XVLRValue value : values){
            LOG.info("\n --- --- --- value:"+value+"\n");
            textForOutput.set(print(key, value));
            context.write(key.getMsisdn(), textForOutput);
        }
    }

    private String print(XVLRKey key, XVLRValue value){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(value.getLac())          .append("\t")
               .append(value.getCellId())       .append("\t")
               .append(key.getDateOccurrence()) .append("\t")
               .append(value.getTimeDelta());
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Job code:

```
JobBuilder<POIJob> jobBuilder = createTestableJobInstance();

        jobBuilder.withOutputKey(XVLRKey.class);
        jobBuilder.withOutputValue(XVLRValue.class);

        jobBuilder.withMapper(POIMapper.class);
        jobBuilder.withReducer(POIReducer.class);

        jobBuilder.withInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        jobBuilder.withOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        jobBuilder.withPartitioner(XVLRKeyPartitioner.class);
        jobBuilder.withSortComparator(XVLRCompositeKeyComparator.class);
        jobBuilder.withGroupingComparator(XVLRKeyGroupingComparator.class);

        boolean result = buildSubmitAndWaitForCompletion(jobBuilder);
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(result, Matchers.is(true));




public class XVLRKeyPartitioner extends Partitioner<XVLRKey, XVLRValue> {

    @Override
    public int getPartition(XVLRKey key, XVLRValue value, int numPartitions) {
            return Math.abs(key.getMsisdn().hashCode() * 127) % numPartitions;
    }
}

public class XVLRCompositeKeyComparator extends WritableComparator {

    protected XVLRCompositeKeyComparator() {
        super(XVLRKey.class, true);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable writable1, WritableComparable writable2) {
        XVLRKey key1 = (XVLRKey) writable1;
        XVLRKey key2 = (XVLRKey) writable2;
       return key1.compareTo(key2);
    }
}

public class XVLRKeyGroupingComparator extends WritableComparator {

    protected XVLRKeyGroupingComparator() {
        super(XVLRKey.class, true);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable writable1, WritableComparable writable2) {

        XVLRKey key1 = (XVLRKey) writable1;
        XVLRKey key2 = (XVLRKey) writable2;

        return key1.getMsisdn().compareTo(key2.getMsisdn());

    }
}

public class XVLRKey implements WritableComparable<XVLRKey>{

    private  final LongWritable msisdn;
    private  final LongWritable dateOccurrence;
    private  final BooleanWritable state;
//getters-setters
}

public class XVLRValue implements WritableComparable<XVLRValue> {

    private final LongWritable lac;
    private final LongWritable cellId;
    private final LongWritable timeDelta;
    private final LongWritable dateOccurrence;
    private final BooleanWritable state;
//getters-setterrs
}
```

Please see that XVLRKey, XVLRValue do have duplicated fields. I've duplicated dateOccurrence, state in XVLRKey because I want to get sorted values in my reducer. They should be sorted by dateOccurrence.

I can't find a way how to solve this problem without duplication.

Answer (score 0):

In secondary sort situations (like you describe) the value of the key you have changes when you retrieve the next value from the iterator.

This happens because the Hadoop framework reuses the instances of the objects in order to avoid object creation and garbage collection as much as possible.

So when you call the "next()" the framework also changes the data inside the key instance.

So if you move the

```
    LOG.info("\nPOIReducer: key:"+key);
```

statement so that it is inside the for loop you should see all the keys come by.

Because of this effect I make my jobs with essentially the following "rule":

> The key is ONLY used by the framework to direct the values to the
>   right reducer.

This implies that

1. Everything I may need must be present in the value.
2. In the reducer I only look at the value and I always discard/ignore the key.
3. The properties that are used to create the key can also be found in the value.

Comment: Ok. So I did implement key, sorter, grouper, partitioner correctly? Now i can remove duplicated values from XVLRValue, yes? These values would be updated after calling iterator.next() got from Iterable<XVLRValue>? Right now my solution does pass QA test (etalon input, etalon output test). But data duplication is bad. So I try to remove it and see how key value is changed?

Comment: I can't tell if you implemented everything correctly. I assume you implemented the correct compareTo method for your key and value classes? If not then it will do a byte by byte compare.